# PL SQL code that Inserts data from a different table and gives new id values from the same table that the data is being inserted

Tags: query, insert, plsql, oracle-apex

What could I change to make this insert work and give a new ID value on each row I am inserting? Right now it's giving all the inserted rows the same ID number. Sadly, I can't use triggers and sequences so that's not an option.

```sql
INSERT INTO shema1.W_ITEM_TABLE("C_ID", "KID", "Number", "LastStatusTime", "AddTime", "Status")
select (select max("C_ID")+1 from shema1.W_ITEM_TABLE), KID, TALRUNIS, NULL,NULL,NULL
from ROBO_SYSTEM;
```

TABLES:

```
shema1.W_ITEM_TABLE("C_ID", "KID", "Number", "LastStatusTime", "AddTime", "Status")

ROBO_SYSTEM(KID, TALRUNIS,)
```

Comment: I'm assuming you use the Oracle database; what version? Please consider following [these suggestions](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql/2977#2977).

Comment: The target table should have a designated method for generating those values; don't just make one up randomly. Ideally you should use a dedicated sequence object to generate the new ID values.

Comment: The value of `max("C_ID")+1` is only evaluated *once* for the select query result set, not on a row-by-row basis. If you want to do this in a single SQL command, you'll have to use a sequence. Can you create PL/SQL blocks, or are you limited to simple SQL?

Comment: As I mentioned before, I can't use triggers and sequences so that's not an option. However, I did solve my problem by making a loop procedure.